# How do I format a string with both trailing and leading zeros?

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting, tostring

What is the `ToString` format needed to produce this?

```
>     5  to 00000500
>     10 to 00001000
>     15 to 00001500
>     20 to 00002000
```

Comment: This MSDN page has information on how to pad a number with leading zeros - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Comment: What should it do for 300, or 4000?

Comment: Numbers need to be formatted will never exceed 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want do this purely with a `ToString` format string, rather than involving a multiplication too, then you could use something like this:

```
string yourString = yourNumber.ToString("000000'00'");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
(yourNum * 100).ToString("0000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(number * 100).ToString("D8");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a custom format provider. Provided, the input is a string. Its easy to change to any datatype though. Just change the `if (arg.GetType() == typeof(String))` to anything you want to format.

Usage:

```
            var five = "5";
            var ten = "10";
            var fiveteen = "15";
            var twenty = "20";

        var formatprovider = new CustomStringFormatProvider();
        var res1 = string.Format(formatprovider, "{0}", five);
        res1 = string.Format(formatprovider, "{0}", ten);
        res1 = string.Format(formatprovider, "{0}", fiveteen);
        res1 = string.Format(formatprovider, "{0}", twenty);
```

And here's the format provider

```
public sealed class CustomStringFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public Object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) return this;
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.GetFormat(formatType);
    }
    public String Format(String format, Object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        String s;

        IFormattable formattable = arg as IFormattable;

        if (formattable == null) s = arg.ToString();
        else s = formattable.ToString(format, formatProvider);

        if (arg.GetType() == typeof(String))
            return String.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat("0", 4).ToArray()) + s + String.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat("0", 4 - s.Length).ToArray());
        return s;
    }
}
```